# JavaScript instantiates class without usage React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, class, constructor

I have the next problem/question in React Native:

I have the next class, let's say it `A` that looks like this:

```
    export default class A {
        static shared = A.shared || new A()
    
        constructor() {
            console.log('in constructor')
            testFunction()
        }
    
        testFunction = () => {
           console.log('in test function')
        }

        testFunction2 = () => {
           console.log('in test function 2')
        }
    }
```

My `A` class in used in `B` class like this:

```
export default class B {
    static shared = B.shared || new B()

    makeAPIRequest = (parameters, valueCallback, errorCallback) => {
        console.log('in B req')
        A.shared.testFunction2()
    }
}
```

And the `makeApiRequest` function from `B` class in used in `App.js` like this:

```
const makeRequest = () => {
    B.shared.makeAPIRequest(parameters, responseCallback => {
      // do logic here...
    }, errorCallback => {
      // do logic here
    })   
}
```

And this `makeRequest` function is placed as an `onPress` action.

My question is:
**At the first render of the app, my `constructor` console.log and called function console.log are printed in terminal. Shouldn't this happen just before I call the `makeRequest` function is `App.js` that calls the `makeAPIRequest` from `B` class that instantiate the `A` class?**

If someone can explain me the logic behind this, will be pretty appreciated.

Comment: Does calling `new A()` inside `A` cause some kind of infinite loop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope, this is just so if there is already an instantiated `A` class, use it, otherwise, create e new one.
My `console.logs` are printed just once in terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` is instantiated as static dependency of itself so basically that happens just after class is loaded, if you want to make it lazy instantiated you need to do something like:

```
class A {
    static get shared() {
        if (!this.__instance) {
            this.__instance = new this();
        }
        return this.__instance;
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: but tbh mostly singletons are evil, re-think if you really need it, there is only few exceptions when that pattern is a good choice

Comment: this class is used as a request manager, which i thought is the best to have a singleton over the whole app for it